# Permissions with partner communities

Tags: reporting, community

I'm working with partner communities, I intend to give permissions to a report to a partner user and I get the following error "Insufficient Privileges You do not have access to run this report. Contact your administrator if you need access." I'm sure I gave permissions to the folder and the dashboard, but does not allow me to see the detail of the report, someone has any idea that I might be missing? how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the problem was totally permissions on the user's profile of communities to solve the problem, I got to download the xml files of the profiles and take the one I need and a very similar profile and start comparing field by field, class by class and page by page, the differences and add the missing permissions profile, as there were custom objects that could not see from the home page.